# Show Bootstrap 5 Modal in react on conditional situation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.13 on my react project.
Now i would like to show a Modal when the form is submit and the backend confirm that the data is saved sucessfuly.

I have created a component with modal script from bootstrap:

```
const Modal = () => {

  return(
        
    <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
        ...
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Then in my form component i have this conditional:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {    
    e.preventDefault();   
    dispatch(setDesignResponse(dataResponse));    
    dispatch(createNewVariations(variations));
    dispatch(createNewJsonResponse(newJsonResponse));  
    
    // window.location ='/corpus';
    
  };  
  
  if(isCreated === true && isVariationsSave === true) {  
    <Modal />;    
    
  }
```

But the modal not works. I see that modal.show() is an option, but in bootstrap 5 with react i don't achieve that works.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad. Here, a new code. Please forget about bootstrap first. You can style or edit Modal component as you want. Add any props you want. But basic is one `boolean value` and one `close function` and `position` styling for full screen. This is how you make your own modal.

```
export default function App() {
  const [show,setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=> setShow(true)}>Show Modal</button>
      <Modal visible={show} onClose={()=> setShow(false)} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Modal(props){
  if (!props.visible) return;

  return (
    <div style={{position: "fixed", top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"}}>
      <h1>This is modal component</h1>
      <button onClick={props.onClose}>Close Modal</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you still want bootstraps, here is full code. No need to update `state`. No `props` needed. But you need to add `bootstrap javascript`. Make sure you added

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this `bootstrap javascript` to your react folder's `public/index.html`, right after `<div id="root"></div>` inside `<body>` tag.

```
export default function App() {
      
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
      >
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      <Modal />
    </div>
  );
}

function Modal() {
  return (
    <div
      className="modal fade"
      id="exampleModal"
      tabIndex="-1"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
              Modal title
            </h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">...</div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-secondary"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
              Save changes
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: are you sure visible and onClose are props for Modal in Bootstrap 5.1?

Comment: No, you have to add `onClose` button by yourself, like `X` button on top right cornor, and visible is just props.

Comment: This not work for me. i have in my main function inside the conditional <Modal visible={true} /> and in my component const Modal = (props) => { if(props) { return (modal html from bootstrap 5)} export default modal.

Comment: it is not `if(props)`. it is `if(props.visible)`.

Comment: still not works. i don't how this prop (booblean) active the modal. without any change in the modal component in bootstrap 5.1.